# phpmyadmin shows tables in the sidebar but tables don't exist

Tags: mysql

I re-installed wampserver 2.5 (with same stuff/settings - nothing changed) and after installation my database got corrupted. Few database tables exist and many of them are not accessible. On right frame it shows `No tables found in database.`

Even the sidebar of phpmyadmin shows my database table

[image]

but when I try to open any table it says:

[image]

To confirm whether tables exists in database, I go to

`C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.17\data\db_blog`

where I can see a long list of stuff. My tables are listed in 2 different formats `frm` and `idb`.

[image]

How can I repair my database? Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Before reinstalling wamp you should have done backup of database and after reinstall bring database back from backup. If after reinstall of wamp database is still available but seems to be corrupted then there you did something wrong with wamp reinstall as database should be purged or not touched, nothing in between. Now everything depends on what you want to achieve: you can purge databases simply using phpmyadmin or try to somehow restore database but it is possible only if you have backup of database, otherwise data is corrupted and can't be restored. You may try to repair database by following this article but do not expect miracles:

https://www.a2hosting.com/kb/cpanel/cpanel-database-features/optimizing-and-repairing-mysql-databases-with-phpmyadmin

Comment: I have complete www folder backup. I put my backup database folder in `C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.17\data` but still database is not accessible in phpmyadmin. What to do?

Comment: After overwriting /data files i'm getting #2002 - No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

The server is not responding (or the local server's socket is not correctly configured).

Comment: Sounds like you did backup wrong. To make a backup you are supposed to export database to a file and later import it from exported file. It shouldn't be operated on in form of files and folders. Example guide: https://support.managed.com/kb/a2034/how-to-backup-and-or-restore-your-mysql-database-using-phpmyadmin.aspx